# Question about SharePoint my site keyword

Tags: people-search

I am wondering if any of you know what LTE stands for? I received an email from our SharePoint site suggesting that I use the keyword LTE in my site profile. When I did a search for my answer I found that SharePoint often suggests LTD as a key word but not usually LTE. When I did a search on just LTE the search came back with "Long Term Evolution." If this is the case I am not sure how it pertains to me. I started working on building this site about a year ago and yes it was the first SharePoint project I ever worked on. But it is my understanding that Long Term Evolution involved telecommunications. How would that relate to what I am doing?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=LTE&l=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each time a user starts to tag an item in SharePoint 2010, the Keywords portion of the Term Store is queried in real time to see if suggestions can be made to the user about previous keywords that other users have used. If a keyword appears in the list of suggestions and the user deems it suitable, the user can use it to tag the item. If not, the user can add their own unique keyword to the Keywords store and then it will be available for SharePoint 2010 to use as a suggestion in the future for other users. ([Source](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.se/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-social-networkingpart-3.html))

So basically, probably one or more of your collegues likes the keyword "LTE", hence SharePoint thinks you should to!

The email is sent by the Timer Job named "User Profile My Site Suggestions Email Job" that you can disable if you want SharePoint to stop sending suggestions!

(Ps. I know that the first quote is more general and applies to filling in terms, but the timerjob should work in a similiar way)

Comment: Thank you Robert. That even made it more confusing as I do not believe anyone else is using the site as yet. We are about to go live with it and these My Site Suggestions just started about a week ago. I will turn them off for now. There is a lot of other things that we need to be concerned about with the new launch.

Comment: No problem, I do think the timer job is only set to run every 14th day, and too only address people who have previously updated their profile, but not done any changes for some time. SO technically it should not interfere with your release.